# Using boolean expressions in if statement?

Tags: bash

I want to do an if then statement: If variable i is equal to the regex for 0 through 9 AND if grep does not return any results, then do something.  Is this the correct syntax?

```
if [[ $i =~ [0-9] ]] && if ! grep $i /opt/tftpboot/*; then
```

or is it

```
if [[ $i =~ [0-9] ]] && ! [[ grep $i /opt/tftpboot/* ]]; then
```

Comment: Note that `if` in a shell is somewhat different to other languages: what follows `if` are **commands** (see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs), not any special syntax. `[[` is a bash/ksh/zsh built-in command. The exit status of the commands is used by `if`.

Answer (score 4):

It's:

```
if [[ $i =~ [0-9] ]] && ! grep $i /opt/tftpboot/*; then
```

You probably don't need the output of `grep`, in which case you can do:

```
if [[ $i =~ [0-9] ]] && ! grep -q $i /opt/tftpboot/*; then
```